# Jquery menu widget to every link seen in html

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want to create a pop-up menu beside every link seen in an html content that is retrieved from curl. When user right clicks the link, a dropdown menu is shown beside the link using z-index where users can change the font style or color of the text. I am currently using jquery and twitter bootstrap. Can someone guide me if there is any plugin or codes that allow to getting started?

Let say the html content is such:

```
<pre>
 <div class="navbar">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: I am stuck as i am doing search online to find a way to do this :-?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 5 plugins that maybe fit in your project: 
http://www.jquery4u.com/menus/right-click-context-menu-plugins/

Comment: will look at this and see. I just need clues.